# Switching views with Grails Portlet Plugin

Tags: grails, liferay, portlet

I've been trying to use the Grails Portlet Plugin along with Liferay, but I can't seem to be able to render different pages regardless of what the tutorials say:

> #### View Mapping
>
> for those request types that support it ('resource', 'render'), a model can be returned by having the portlet action closure return a map. The model will be passed to a view using the following rules (in order of precedent):
>
> 1. 'XXX/xyz.gsp' where 'XXX' is the name of the portlet (e.g. XXXPortlet.groovy) and 'xyz' is the value of the 'action' parameter on the request.
> 2. 'XXX/MODE.gsp'where 'XXX' is the name of the portlet (e.g. XXXPortlet.groovy) and 'MODE' is the current portlet mode (e.g. 'view')
> 3. 'XXX/render.gsp'

So far I have been able to trigger specific actions via this code:

```
<form method="post" action="${portletResponse.createActionURL()}">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="testPage"/>
    <input type="submit" value="action">
</form>
```

which will trigger a code block:

```
 def testPage = {
    println "TESTPAGE METHOD"
 }
```

However afterwards it will always render the View.gsp, unlike the XXX/testPage.gsp it says will work.

Additionally I have tried to use createRenderURL() instead of createActionURL() but the portlet will render a blank page and I can't seem to be able to find in the logs what page it is attempting to find.

Any help with this would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out by diving into the plugin groovy and wanted to document the answer for anyone else who was having issues. You must use the portletResponse.createRenderURL() as the action, and additionally you **MUST** return a map from the method invoked.

Here is an example:

```
<form method="post" action="${portletResponse.createRenderURL()}">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="testPage"/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

would invoke the following code and render it to the XXX/testPage.gsp view

```
def testPage = {
    println "TESTPAGE METHOD"
    ['PageProperty1':'foo', 'PageProperty2':'bar']
}
```

The important thing to note here is that createRenderURL() will simply call the closure specified by the value of the action parameter, and redirect to the that page if it exists where as the createActionURL() will simply invoke the closure and redirect to view.gsp.